# Comparing opencv lineartoPolar() transformation in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, polar-coordinates, cartesian

My objective is to convert a 2D power spectrum (below) from cartesian to polar coordinates.

```
imshow(np.log10(psd2shift),cmap=cm.jet)
```

[image]
There are several posts on stackoverflow on how to do just that such as this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51675940/converting-an-image-from-cartesian-to-polar-limb-darkening). And so I believe my code is right.

```
ro,col=psd2shift.shape
cent=(int(ro/2),int(col/2))
max_radius = int(np.sqrt(ro**2+col**2)/2)
polar=cv.linearPolar(np.log10(psd2shift),cent,max_radius,cv.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)
plt.imshow(polar,cmap=cm.jet, interpolation='bicubic')
```

[image]

Nonetheless I am not getting what I want which is this:
[image]

Obviously there is a difference in the transformation that I have not been able to uncover despite digging into the help of linearPolar function or the documentation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html). It almost seems that the center is not defined right, but I am pretty sure it is.Thoughts?

With `help(cv.linearPolar)`
Returns:
Help on built-in function linearPolar:

```
linearPolar(...)
    linearPolar(src, center, maxRadius, flags[, dst]) -> dst
    .   @brief Remaps an image to polar coordinates space.
    .   
    .   @anchor polar_remaps_reference_image
    .   ![Polar remaps reference](pics/polar_remap_doc.png)
    .   
    .   Transform the source image using the following transformation:
    .   \f[\begin{array}{l}
    .   dst( \rho , \phi ) = src(x,y) \\
    .   dst.size() \leftarrow src.size()
    .   \end{array}\f]
    .   
    .   where
    .   \f[\begin{array}{l}
    .   I = (dx,dy) = (x - center.x,y - center.y) \\
    .   \rho = Kx \cdot \texttt{magnitude} (I) ,\\
    .   \phi = Ky \cdot \texttt{angle} (I)_{0..360 deg}
    .   \end{array}\f]
    .   
    .   and
    .   \f[\begin{array}{l}
    .   Kx = src.cols / maxRadius \\
    .   Ky = src.rows / 360
    .   \end{array}\f]
    .   
    .   
    .   @param src Source image
    .   @param dst Destination image. It will have same size and type as src.
    .   @param center The transformation center;
    .   @param maxRadius The radius of the bounding circle to transform. It determines the inverse magnitude scale parameter too.
    .   @param flags A combination of interpolation methods, see cv::InterpolationFlags
    .   
    .   @note
    .   -   The function can not operate in-place.
    .   -   To calculate magnitude and angle in degrees @ref cv::cartToPolar is used internally thus angles are measured from 0 to 360 with accuracy about 0.3 degrees.
```

Comment: It would help if you include your original image (`psd2shift`).

Comment: I mean the actual image, not one that displayed by `plt.imshow`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first impression is that you might have messed up the center's coordinates. Points in OpenCV are refered as `(x,y)` which is confusingly translated to `(col, row)`. Swapping those in your code

```
ro,col=img.shape
cent=(int(col/2),int(ro/2))
max_radius = int(np.sqrt(ro**2+col**2)/2)
polar=cv2.linearPolar(img,cent,max_radius,cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)

plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))
plt.imshow(polar,cmap='jet', interpolation='bicubic')
plt.show()
```

I get the image, which I think is close to what you want.

[image]

Comment: That was a good revelation. Here is comprehensive explanation of this confusion point. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642532/opencv-pointx-y-represent-column-row-or-row-column#25644503